# entity framework c# where

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

how can I read from entity Framework?

I use this to insert items:

```
    public void Insert()
    {
        using (HistoryContainer db = new HistoryContainer())
        {
            HistoryData e = new HistoryData();
            e.MP = IpAddress;
            e.Number = OtherPartyNumber;
            e.DateTimeStart = DateTime.Now;
            e.Duration = duration;
            e.TypeDescription = type;
            e.text = e.text;
            db.AddToHistoryDataSet(e);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I tried this to read them:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<HistoryContainer> ReadFirst()
    {
        using (HistoryContainer x = new HistoryContainer())
        {
            foreach (var item in HistoryData.where(b => b.MP == IpAddress))
            {
                _history.Add(new HistoryItem(item));
            } 
        }
    }
```

But it didn't work. What's wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: What doesn't work? What error do you get?

Comment: What does 'db.AddToHistoryDataSet(e)' do? Did you make this method, or was it generated? Also, is the value of IpAddress still the correct one?

Comment: Error: 'Project.HistoryContainer' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Project.HistoryContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
        
What should I repair?
The IpAddress is correct.
The generated method AddToHistory is: 
        public void AddToHistoryDataSet(HistoryData historyData)
        {
            base.AddObject("HistoryDataSet", historyData);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public virtual HistoryData ReadFirst()
    {
        using (HistoryContainer db = new HistoryContainer())
        {
            return db.HistoryData.Where(x => x.MP == IpAddress).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error: 'Project.HistoryContainer' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Project.HistoryContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) What should I repair?

Comment: @sylon - This doesn't really answer the question why it doesn't work, does it?

Comment: @Pch it should be db.HistoryData.Where.  Sorry.

Comment: @Maarten  Not sure i think the code looks completely weird in the question, it seems more like the OP needs to do some reading on how to use EF.

Comment: @sylon If I write db.HistoryData.Where or x.HistoryData.Where or something like that - underlined 'HistoryData' and error:  'Project.HistoryContainer' does not contain a definition for 'HistoryData' and no extension method 'HistoryData' accepting a first argument of type 'Project.HistoryContainer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It works :)
'public virtual IEnumerable<HistoryContainer> ReadFirst()
    {
        using (HistoryContainer db = new HistoryContainer())
        {
            foreach (var item in db.HistoryDataSet.Where(x => x.MP == IpAddress))
            {
                _history.Add(new HistoryItem(item));
            }
        }
    }'

The correct solution is 'db.HistoryDataSet.Where(x => x.MP == IpAddress))'. And there is another error with '_history.Add(new HistoryItem(item));' but I hope that I can do this myself.

Thank to all.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot your Container in the foreach statement

```
public virtual IEnumerable<HistoryContainer> ReadFirst()
{
    using (HistoryContainer x = new HistoryContainer())
    {
        foreach (var item in x.HistoryData.where(b => b.MP == IpAddress))
        {
            _history.Add(new HistoryItem(item));
        } 
    }
}
```